# Open Source Software to open .aep file?

Tags: after-effects

I've an envato subscription and have access to .aep files but don't have adobe after effects.

I want to do a company video using the .aep but don't want to have to purchase AE for the edit.  Are there any open source editors that will open an aep file?

Answer (score 2):

The best option you have is to use the trial version of after effects. You can create an adobe creative cloud account and try the program for 30 days free of charge there. If it's only one job and you're using a template, the trial time should be sufficient. If not, there's always the option of creating a different account with another mail and beginning the trial anew.